# Simplifications with logarithms and square roots

Tags: logarithms

I am confused about an approximation that I see in a paper on the quadratic sieve.

I have the following result (given from prior calculations):

$\log u \approx \frac{1}{2}(\log ( \log X))$,

where $u$ and $X$ can be seen as variables. From this, the author derives directly

$u \approx \sqrt{\frac{2\log X}{\log (\log X)}}$.

I have been trying to understand this result but I can't seem to see what are the steps from going to $\log u$ to $ u$ (obviously, here is not just a matter of taking $e^{\log u}$). Is there any relation between the $\log$ and the square root ?

Pomerance exact reference:

"We are looking at the simplier expression
\begin{equation*}
X^{1/u}u^u
\end{equation*}

We would like to choose $u$ so as to minimize this expression. Take logarithms: so we are to minimize
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{u}\log X + u \log u
\end{equation*}
The derivative is $0$ when $u^2(\log u + 1) = \log X$. Taking the $\log$ of this equation, we find that $\log u \approx \frac{1}{2}\log\log X$, so that
\begin{equation*}
u \approx (2\log X / \log\log X)^{1/2}"
\end{equation*}

Comment: Do you mean $\log(X \log X)$ or $(\log X)(\log X)$?  Parentheses are helpful here.

Comment: Notice that this is to be an **approximation**, not an exact calculation.

Comment: Now you lost an $X$.

Comment: I correct the parenthesis, sorry for the confusion. It is indeed $\log (\log X)$. I know this is an approximation, but I am confused at which step to take, or which approximation to use to obtain the square root with the fraction

Comment: this calculation is taken from "Smooth numbers and the quadratic sieve" by Pomerance, p.77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.  Let's work backwards.
$$ u \approx \sqrt{\frac{2\log X}{\log(\log X)}}$$
i.e.
$$ u = (1 + o(1)) \sqrt{\frac{2 \log X}{\log(\log X)}}$$
would imply
$$ \eqalign{\log u &= \log(1 + o(1)) + \frac{1}{2} \log \log X - \frac{1}{2} \log \log \log X + \frac{1}{2} \log 2\cr
&= \frac{1}{2} \log \log X - \frac{1}{2} \log \log \log X + \frac{1}{2} \log 2 + o(1)}$$ 
which implies, but is not implied by, 
$$\log u \approx \frac{1}{2} \log \log X$$
I suspect you're misinterpreting Pomerance.  What is the exact quote?

EDIT: OK, so there **is** more to it than just $\log u \approx \dfrac{1}{2} \log \log X$, there is an equation
$$ u^2 (\log u + 1) = \log X \tag{1}$$
That does indeed imply
$$ \log u  \approx \frac{1}{2} \log \log X$$
and then you put this in for $\log u$ (or $\log u + 1$) in (1) to get
$$\frac{u^2 \log \log X}{2}\approx \log X$$
multiply by $2/\log \log X$ and then take square roots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which makes complete sense. So, let me write his exact quote as I am now confused at why he states this! ' I added the exact quote in the question